# Logstash agent not indexing anymore

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a Logstash instance running as a service that reads from Redis and outputs to Elasticsearch. I just noticed there was nothing new in Elasticsearch for the last few days, but the Redis lists were increasing.

Logstash log was filled with 2 errors repeated for thousands of lines:

```
:message=>"Got error to send bulk of actions"
:message=>"Failed to flush outgoing items"
```

The reason being:

```
{"error":"IllegalArgumentException[Malformed action/metadata line [107], expected a simple value for field [_type] but found [START_ARRAY]]","status":500},
```

Additionally, trying to stop the service failed repeatedly, I had to kill it. Restarting it emptied the Redis lists and imported everything to Elasticsearch. It seems to work ok now.

But I have no idea how to prevent that from happening again. The mentioned `type` field is set as a string for each input directive, so I don't understand how it could have become an array.
What am I missing?

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7.1 and Logstash 1.5.3. The `logstash.conf` file looks like this:

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 6381
    data_type => "list"
    key => "b2c-web"
    type => "b2c-web"
    codec => "json"
  }
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 6381
    data_type => "list"
    key => "b2c-web-staging"
    type => "b2c-web-staging"
    codec => "json"
  }

    /* other redis inputs, only key/type variations */
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["msg", "Cache hit %{WORD:query} in %{NUMBER:hit_total:int}ms. Network: %{NUMBER:hit_network:int} ms.     Deserialization %{NUMBER:hit_deserial:int}"]
    add_tag => ["cache_hit"]
    tag_on_failure => []
  }
  /* other groks, not related to type field */
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "[IP]"
    port => "9200"
    protocol=> "http"
    cluster => "logstash-prod-2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your config or at least an excerpt where you set the type field? It seems to be related to the elasticsearch bulk api: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11458

Comment: Indeed that issue looks similar, but with array issue instead of null.

Comment: Can you clear logstash.log file, update your elasticsearch-logstash connection plugin and restart it. I had a similar issue and in my case my elasticsearch went down first in b/w and after restarting i had some plugin issue and connection issues.

Comment: Was this ever solved? dealing with the same thing right now.

Comment: @Nate this sounds like something wrong was sent via the bulk request. What's the error in your case? The same? About `_type`? Are you using Logstash?

Comment: Same error about `_type`, and yes I'm using Logstash.

Comment: Can you identify the document that was attempted to be indexed and failed with that error? Or the bulk request?

Comment: @Antoine can you run your logstash process with `--debug` so we can see what's in the bulk payload, since the error is about `_type` being wrong (i.e. this is the `_type` field in the bulk command line)?

Comment: @Antoine, you might also want to add `action.bulk: TRACE` into your Elasticsearch `config/logging.yml` file so you can see how it looks like from the ES side.

Comment: @Antoine, did you try what I suggested above so we get more insights into what's going on?

Comment: @Val, I'm sorry but I haven't tried your suggestions. Unfortunately I don't have the time to investigate this right now. And the issue has not re-occurred yet.

Comment: @Nate what about you? did you try since you opened the bounty?

Comment: @Val the error occurred when I would shut down our logstash indexer before our logstash shippers, and only occasionally. To mitigate this, I created a script which safely shuts down all shippers before the indexer, and awakens the indexer before all shippers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log message:

> {"error":"IllegalArgumentException[Malformed action/metadata line [107], expected a simple value for field [_type] but found [START_ARRAY]]","status":500},

It seems you're trying to index a document with a `type` field that's an array instead of a string.

I can't help you without more of the `logstash.conf` file.
But check followings to make sure:

1. When you use `add_field` for changing the `type` you actually turn `type` into an `array` with multiple values, which is what Elasticsearch is complaining about.
2. You can use `mutate join` to convert arrays to strings: [api link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html)

   ```
   filter {
       mutate {
           join => { "fieldname" => "," }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I had forgotten to update this question when I found out, but indeed the mutate filter fixed the issue.